# how to use plain php variables in to $_SESSION[] variable?

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I'm a newbie to PHP. I'm having a problem with assigning normal variable's value to session variable. 
Supppose I've a variable `$abc=28;` and I want to assign this variable to `$_SESSION[]` array then how to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assign value to session:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['session_name']= $abc;
```

retrive session value:

```
echo $_SESSION['session_name'];
```

Comment: @Dale. Yes it's true but my friend these typo error could be understandable, look at the logic only, you will get your answer.

Comment: @Sushil Sorry but on a forum specifically made for Programming questions and an answer specially for a programming issue should not be only about logic, it has to satisfy the language requirements also.

Comment: PHP does not only look at the logic

Comment: I concur, also posting code with errors as answers will create situations where others who use the code will use it verbatim and may very well end up posting on this site asking *"What's wrong with my code?"*

Comment: yes  Hanky Panky ㇱ you are absolutely right. I'll also take care while studying as well as writing the answers here. Thx for ur suggestion.

Comment: In fact, PHP would not even care for your logic. If your logic is wrong it will only result in the code not producing your desired output. But if the syntax is wrong then the code won't even run. So syntax is important first.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
session_start();
$abc=28;
$_SESSION["abc"]=$abc;
?>
```

However you have to know that `$abc` is a different variable and `$_SESSION` is different. Even with the assignment above they do not somehow get `connected`; that is to say that after assignment if you change the value of `$abc` then value of `$_SESSION["abc"]` will not change automatically, Just FYI.

Edit:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["abc"]=28;   // Yes this will work perfectly fine.
?>
```

Comment: Thx for your help. But if I use only $_SESSION["abc"] without assigning a value of $abc to it as you did in 3rd step. Won't it be worked?

Comment: @Sushil you should really try these basic things before asking on here

Comment: @HankyPankyㇱ: Thx so much for your help. As I'm a newbie I'm having difficulties with session. Thx for understanding me.

Comment: Newbie is a lame excuse. Don't expect spoonfeeding. Works or not, try it. Then come asking, i tried this but didn't work, why it didn't work?